# How to log a button press with specific info?

Tags: c#, xamarin.forms

I am working on developing a program for my school that tracks when the students leave and come back to class. This program would be on a computer in class, and the students would select their period, name, and where they were going. I have a system already in place where they select their information and press the sign-out button. I will admit there are minor bugs with the program. EX: You can not click the Sign-In or Sign-Out button before all three pickers with the student information are filled out, but if you fill out the pickers, click sign out you can refill out the info click sign out again without aver signing back in.

The next goal that I am stumped on, is to log all signouts sign-out in another `Stacklayout` that is made visible when you click the log button in the top left of the screen and I want it to push the other elements out of the way so it makes the illusion of switching to another page. I have the idea but I'm not sure how to add a label to the stack layout with the picker info when you click sign-out.

Here is the c# code I have at the moment:

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.ComponentModel;
using System.Linq;
using System.Text;
using System.Threading.Tasks;
using Xamarin.Forms;

namespace Sign_In_Out
{
    public partial class MainPage : ContentPage
    {
        string[] firstPeriodNames = { "Kid 1", "Kid 2", "Kid 3", " Kid 4" };
        string[] secondPeriodNames = { "Kid 5", "Kid 6", "Kid 7", " Kid 8" };
        string[] thirdPeriodNames = { "Kid 9", "Kid 10", "Kid 11", " Kid 12" };
        string[] fourthPeriodNames = { "Kid 13", "Kid 14", "Kid 15", " Kid 16" };
        string[] fivePeriodNames = { "Kid 17", "Kid 18", "Kid 19", " Kid 20" };
        string[] sixPeriodNames = { "Kid 21", "Kid 22", "Kid 23", " Kid 24" };
        string[] sevenPeriodNames = { "Kid 25", "Kid 26", "Kid 28", " Kid 28" };

        public MainPage()
        {
            InitializeComponent();

            BindingContext = this;
        }

        private void PeriodPicker_SelectedIndexChanged(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            Picker picker = sender as Picker;
            var selectedItem = picker.SelectedItem;

            if (selectedItem.ToString() == "1st Period")
            {
                kidSelector.ItemsSource = firstPeriodNames;
            } else if (selectedItem.ToString() == "2nd Period")
            {
                kidSelector.ItemsSource = secondPeriodNames;
            }
            else if (selectedItem.ToString() == "3rd Period")
            {
                kidSelector.ItemsSource = thirdPeriodNames;
            }
            else if (selectedItem.ToString() == "4th Period")
            {
                kidSelector.ItemsSource = fourthPeriodNames;
            }
            else if (selectedItem.ToString() == "5th Period")
            {
                kidSelector.ItemsSource = fivePeriodNames;
            }
            else if (selectedItem.ToString() == "6th Period")
            {
                kidSelector.ItemsSource = sixPeriodNames;
            }
            else if (selectedItem.ToString() == "7th Period")
            {
                kidSelector.ItemsSource = sevenPeriodNames;
            }

            if (PeriodPicker.SelectedItem != null && kidSelector.SelectedItem != null && destination.SelectedItem != null)
            {
                SignOut.IsEnabled = true;
            }
            else
            {
                SignOut.IsEnabled = false;
            }
        }

        private void SignInButton(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            SignOut.IsEnabled = true;
            BackgroundColor = Color.ForestGreen;
            SignIn.IsEnabled = false;
        }

        private void SignOutButton(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            SignIn.IsEnabled = true;
            BackgroundColor = Color.Red;
            destination.SelectedIndex = -1;
            kidSelector.SelectedIndex = -1;
            PeriodPicker.SelectedIndex = 0;
            SignOut.IsEnabled = false;
        }

        private void kidSelector_SelectedIndexChanged(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            if (PeriodPicker.SelectedItem != null && kidSelector.SelectedItem != null && destination.SelectedItem != null)
            {
                SignOut.IsEnabled = true;
            }
            else
            {
                SignOut.IsEnabled = false;
            }
        }

        private void destination_SelectedIndexChanged(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            if (PeriodPicker.SelectedItem != null && kidSelector.SelectedItem != null && destination.SelectedItem != null)
            {
                SignOut.IsEnabled = true;
            }
            else
            {
                SignOut.IsEnabled = false;
            }
        }

        private void LogButtonClicked(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {

        }

        private void AdminButtonClicked(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {

        }
    }
}
```

And here is the Xamarin code:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8" ?>
<ContentPage xmlns="http://xamarin.com/schemas/2014/forms"
             xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2009/xaml"
             x:Class="Sign_In_Out.MainPage"
             BackgroundColor="ForestGreen"
             NavigationPage.HasNavigationBar="False">

    <StackLayout>
        <StackLayout Orientation="Horizontal" HorizontalOptions="End">
            <Button Clicked="AdminButtonClicked" Text="Admin" Margin="0" BackgroundColor="Black" VerticalOptions="End"></Button>
            <Button Clicked="LogButtonClicked" Text="Log" Margin="0" BackgroundColor="Black" VerticalOptions="End"></Button>
        </StackLayout>
        <StackLayout IsVisible="False" x:Name="Admin">
            <Label Text="Admin"></Label>
        </StackLayout>
        <StackLayout IsVisible="False" x:Name="Log">
            <Label Text="Log"></Label>
        </StackLayout>
        <StackLayout>
            <Grid>
                <Grid.RowDefinitions>
                   <RowDefinition Height="1*"></RowDefinition>
                </Grid.RowDefinitions>
                <Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
                    <ColumnDefinition Width="3*"></ColumnDefinition>
                    <ColumnDefinition Width="3*"></ColumnDefinition>
                    <ColumnDefinition Width="3*"></ColumnDefinition>
                    <ColumnDefinition Width="3*"></ColumnDefinition>
                    <ColumnDefinition Width="3*"></ColumnDefinition>
                    <ColumnDefinition Width="3*"></ColumnDefinition>
                    <ColumnDefinition Width="3*"></ColumnDefinition>
                </Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
                <Picker x:Name="PeriodPicker" SelectedIndex="0" SelectedIndexChanged="PeriodPicker_SelectedIndexChanged" Grid.Column="1" Margin="0, 150, 0, 0">
                    <Picker.Items>
                        <x:String></x:String>
                        <x:String>1st Period</x:String>
                        <x:String>2nd Period</x:String>
                        <x:String>3rd Period</x:String>
                        <x:String>4th Period</x:String>
                        <x:String>5th Period</x:String>
                        <x:String>6th Period</x:String>
                        <x:String>7th Period</x:String>
                    </Picker.Items>
                </Picker>
                <Picker Grid.Column="3" x:Name="kidSelector" SelectedIndexChanged="kidSelector_SelectedIndexChanged" Margin="0, 150, 0, 0"></Picker>
                <Picker Grid.Column="5" x:Name="destination" SelectedIndexChanged="destination_SelectedIndexChanged" Margin="0, 150, 0, 0">
                    <Picker.Items>
                        <x:String>Bathroom</x:String>
                        <x:String>Office</x:String>
                        <x:String>Clinic</x:String>
                        <x:String>Leaving Early</x:String>
                    </Picker.Items>
                </Picker>
            </Grid>
            <Grid>
                <Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
                    <ColumnDefinition></ColumnDefinition>
                    <ColumnDefinition></ColumnDefinition>
                    <ColumnDefinition></ColumnDefinition>
                    <ColumnDefinition></ColumnDefinition>
                    <ColumnDefinition></ColumnDefinition>
                </Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
                <Button x:Name="SignOut" Grid.Column="1" Margin="0, 125, 0, 0" Clicked="SignOutButton" HeightRequest="150" IsEnabled="False" Text="Sign-Out" FontSize="Large"></Button>
                <Button x:Name="SignIn"  Grid.Column="3" Margin="0, 125, 0, 0" Clicked="SignInButton" HeightRequest="150" IsEnabled="False" Text="Sign-In" FontSize="Large"></Button>
            </Grid>
        </StackLayout>
    </StackLayout>
    

</ContentPage>
```

Thanks in advance to anyone who can help me out.

Comment: "I'm not sure how to add a label to the stack layout" - `layout.Children.Add(new Label { Text = picker.SelectedItem; });`

Answer (score 1):

Instead of using this:

```
if (PeriodPicker.SelectedItem != null && kidSelector.SelectedItem != null && destination.SelectedItem != null)
        {
            SignOut.IsEnabled = true;
        }
        else
        {
            SignOut.IsEnabled = false;
        }
```

you should declare a string like this:

```
...
string[] sevenPeriodNames = { "Kid 25", "Kid 26", "Kid 28", " Kid 28" };
string period = "", kid ="", destination = ""; //<--add this
```

after you declare the string, you can use it like this:

```
private void PeriodPicker_SelectedIndexChanged(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    ...
    ...
    if (PeriodPicker.SelectedIndex != -1)
    { 
         period = PeriodPicker.Items[PeriodPicker.SelectedIndex]; 
    }
}
```

use that for 2 other SelectedIndexChanged, after that you can use that variable in any method that exist in your application.
Let's say you want to use it in SignOutButton Clicked Event:

```
private void SignOutButton(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    if (period != "" && kid != "" && destination != "")
    {
    SignIn.IsEnabled = true;
    BackgroundColor = Color.Red;
    destination.SelectedIndex = -1;
    kidSelector.SelectedIndex = -1;
    PeriodPicker.SelectedIndex = 0;
    SignOut.IsEnabled = false;
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You could create a **SignOutLog** class:

```
public class SignOutLog
{
    public string PeriodNames{ get; set; }
    public string KidNames{ get; set; }
    public string Destination { get; set; }
}
```

then when you click the sign out button,save the SignoutLog information with [Preferences](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/xamarin/essentials/preferences?context=xamarin%2Fxamarin-forms&tabs=android):

```
private void SignOutButton(object sender, EventArgs e)
   {         
        SignIn.IsEnabled = true;
        BackgroundColor = Color.Red;
        destination.SelectedIndex = -1;
        kidSelector.SelectedIndex = -1;
        PeriodPicker.SelectedIndex = 0;
        SignOut.IsEnabled = false;
          
        List<SignOutLog> logs;
        if (Preferences.ContainsKey("sign_out_log"))
        {
            string logsString = Preferences.Get("sign_out_log", "default_value");
            logs = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<List<SignOutLog>>(logsString);
        }
        else
        {
            logs = new List<SignOutLog>();
        }
        SignOutLog log = new SignOutLog () {PeriodNames=PeriodPicker.SelectedItem,KidNames= kidSelector.SelectedItem,Destination = destination.SelectedItem};
        logs.Add(log);
        string logsJsonString = JsonConvert.SerializeObject(logs);
        Preferences.Set("sign_out_log", logsJsonString);  //save the data
      
   }
```

after you clicl the log button,you could push a new page:

```
 private void LogButtonClicked(object sender, EventArgs e)
  {
       Navigation.PushAsync(new LogsPage());
  }
```

in your LogsPage,you could define a listview to display the logs:

```
public partial class LogsPage: ContentPage
{
    public LogsPage()
    {
        InitializeComponent();
     
    }
    protected override void OnAppearing()
    {
        base.OnAppearing();
        string logsString = Preferences.Get("sign_out_log", "default_value");
        List<SignOutLog>  logs = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<List<SignOutLog>>(logsString);
        yourListView.ItemsSource= logs;
    }
}
```